# Word Add-in's start up order

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I have two add-in's installed in my local MS Word app. Both add-ins are implemented as Visual Studio 2010 Office Word Add-in projects. Both projects have ThisAddin.ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) event handlers.

When I debug the solution the second add-in always handles the Word startup event first although it is not set up as a start up project in the solution.
I would expect that the add-in of the startup project handles the Word start up event first. But it is not the case.

I wonder how does Word know which add-in to run first?

Comment: If you log when the event handlers are -created- can you see what addin -created- the event handlers first? See if you can find a correlation between creation and execution order.

Comment: There is no way to determine or specifiy in which order Word loads add-ins (including "template" add-ins). If you need things to execute in a certain order, install your add-ins so that only the first one loads automatically, when Word starts. Install the other to "load on demand", then have the first one load the second.

Comment: @ Maarten. Thank you Maarten for the idea of checking if there is a correlation between handler creation time and execution order.

Comment: @Cindy. Thank you  for your advise. I am new in programming of Office Add-Ins and the idea of using different loading modes is quite helpful.

Comment: @MBK Shall I write it up as an Answer?

Comment: @Cindy. I have no problem with this. The only question I still have is  are you sure the Add-Ins execution order is not defined by their installation order?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that installation order does not affect loading/execution order. I may be wrong and @MaartenvanStam has perhaps some experience with multiple add-ins in a single solution and can check me on this. But I believe once the add-ins are installed and *registered* Word loads them the way it loads them - it doesn't matter which is set as the start-up project in the solution. Looking at old VSTO discussions on msdn I see that - with VBA template files - alphabetical order tends to be used. But Word looks up VSTO Add-ins in the Registry.

Comment: Does it mean that the order of Add-Ins start ups is the same as I see it in HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Office/Word/Addins registry folder? Could you please respond in the answer summarising what we have discussed? I will mark it as the solution to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes, I have some experience with multiple add-ins in a single solution :-) Our scenario was about Ribbon items merging into 1 Ribbon. The main Ribbon had to be there for others to merge. What I found is just like you mention, the (alphabetical) order the Registry stores Addins. What we did was prefixing the Key names (the folders under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\AddIns) with numbers, 10 for the 1st, 20 for the 2nd etc. leaving some room for future ones. What I'm not sure about was if events would also be dependent of the create/load order, hence my suggestion.

Comment: @ Maarten and Cindy. Thank you, guys, for sharing your experience.